# Columns of text in early microcomputers

Tags: apple-ii, video, memory, commodore-pet, trs-80

As discussed in some previous questions here, 80-column text was established by IBM as the standard for business computing as early as the sixties, but monitors capable of displaying that resolution legibly were still somewhat expensive in the seventies, so early microcomputers that used TV sets, or monitors with off-the-shelf TV tubes, such as the trinity of 1977, settled for a lower resolution: 40 columns for the Apple II and Commodore PET, 64 columns for the TRS-80.

As I understand it, a black-and-white TV tube with no color burst signal and the RF stage skipped, while it could not quite reach 80 columns, could handle 64 columns well enough, which raises the question of why Apple and Commodore didn't try for that, or at least for something a bit beyond 40. 64x25 = 1600 bytes, not prohibitive even by the standards of the time.

I get the impression memory bandwidth was a significant limitation, such that when the Apple II later added an 80-column option, the engineering of such involved the careful juxtaposition of two memory banks to provide data at the required rate.

Was memory bandwidth the reason for Apple and Commodore sticking with 40 columns? If so, how did Tandy achieve 64 columns? Is it purely a coincidence that the 64-column machine is the only one of the trinity to use the Z80?

(I'm assuming the Vic-20 later supplying only 22 columns, is not so much due to technical limitations as to the use of a video chip designed more for games than general purpose computing.)

Comment: Two idle thoughts: 40×25 fits neatly into 1 KiB of memory; and many of the 8-bit systems of that generation (Apple II, PET, Atari 8-bit) were *designed* for 4 KiB of RAM as a base configuration, even if they were never sold like that, which doesn’t leave much room if you start expanding the character buffer. (Of course it would have been possible to *plan* for higher-resolution modes, but I get the impression such considerations were unusual in the micro world back then.)

Comment: The way the c64 and probably PETs were designed, more columns would have meant a faster CPU and also faster memory. It might have been impossible.

Comment: Note that 80 columns requires non-square pixels to avoid flicker on an interlaced screen. So b&w with non-square pixels requires a special video mode which adds complexity to the video signal generator, for which you need a b&w screen anyway. It almost makes sense to create separate computer product lines for home and business. In fact, Steve Jobs resisted adding color to the Mac line because he wanted it to remain a business computer.

Comment: The Vic-20's column count is entirely a product of a bandwidth limitation; it actually has and uses much the same bandwidth as a C64 but doesn't have the ability to capture a line of character indices upfront. So half as many characters in the same horizontal space, but also no need to be as prescriptive about how many characters so the display is a little wider.

Comment: The notion of 80 column records goes back a bit further than the 1960s.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card#IBM_80-column_punched_card_format_and_character_codes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't underestimate the cost of additional RAM for display memory!

The TRS-80 used *seven*, not eight, 1x1024 static RAM chips for its display memory. **They left off the eighth chip to reduce cost.** Without it, the machine was limited to uppercase-only display -- one bit per character cell to specify whether that cell displayed a character or a 3x2 graphic tile, and the other bits to specify the character or the state of each graphic block.

It was common to solder an eighth chip piggy-back onto one of the existing display chips. Once you connected that extra data bit to the bus, you could display lowercase -- the character ROM already had lowercase characters and special symbols in its map, it just needed the data to drive it.

At the time these machines were introduced, I think a static 1K chip was still a few bucks. That's a significant chunk in a product like this. It would also have required more board space; in those days of medium-scale TTL DIPs, dual-layer boards, and coarse design rules, each additional part took up quite a bit of room. Bigger board, more expense.

Now, imagine *doubling* the amount of display RAM, *and* requiring a more expensive higher-bandwidth monitor. In the late 1970s, it just didn't make economic sense.

Comment: This is likely to be it more than bandwidth in my opinion; the Apple II is maxing out its bandwidth with the no-sparkle shared bus but if memory serves then the original PET requires a programmer just be careful to leave the video memory alone during the active period. But by my calculation, RAM that's fast enough for a 1Mhz 6502 is fast enough for an 80-column display if permitted to dedicate itself solely to that task. More than fast enough since you can be lazy with RAS.

Comment: @Tommy Good point about having enough bandwidth if the CPU doesn't access memory during active scan line. Now I remember the TRS-80 suffered video glitches when the CPU did so; presumably they didn't have time to design arbitration logic to prevent this. That would explain how that machine got more than 40 columns.

Comment: The TRS-80 has 64 columns by 16 rows, which requires essentially the same amount of display memory as 40x25.  Including a bit to select graphics but not one to select lowercase/reverse video seems a curious choice, though.

Comment: @rwallace IIRC the "arbitration logic" was "if the CPU is accessing video memory when the video circuitry reaches for a byte, feed a value of 0 to the video circuitry." 0 generated a blank (black) cell, so that particular ROW of that particular CELL would show up as black on that particular refresh. End result: when PRINTing stuff to the screen in BASIC, you'd see dark one-pixel-wide horizontal lines flickering on the screen. When you scrolled the screen (block-copying stuff in video RAM), you'd see more flickering (higher duty cycle hitting that RAM).

Comment: @supercat lowercase was still sort of a "luxury feature" on compute hardware at that time. There were lots of uppercase-only devices (teletypes, line printers). Word processors of the time used markup to indicate uppercase ("Hello There" would be entered as "^HELLO ^THERE"). Adding graphics (even crude and blocky) was a bigger selling point than lowercase support.

Comment: @jeffB: The fact that lowercase is a "luxury feature" would be a fine reason to omit lowercase letters from the ROM, since that could cut the size of the ROM in half.  If the ROM includes them, though, getting not just lowercase but *also* reverse video in exchange for one extra RAM chip and a few gates would seem like a rather nice trade.

Comment: @supercat: Yeah, but that ROM was a canned part from Motorola, the MCM6670, prepackaged in an 18-pin DIP. [link](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/555108/MotorolaSemiconductor/MCM6670/7) There was presumably no money to be saved by doing something custom. As for an extra RAM chip and a few more gates, IIRC we actually hijacked unused gates already on the board for the needed logic, but that chip was pure extra cost and footprint (unless you piggy-backed it, which wasn't very manufacturable).

Comment: @jeffB: Some curious character and design choices in that stock font.  I'm not sure for what purpose all the characters in the 00-1F range were expected to serve, and I wonder if the absurdly-tall gpqy characters might have had something to do with the decision not to support lower case.

Comment: @supercat: They weren't lovely, that's for sure. I remember looking for APL characters, but I think that wasn't the answer. The "absurdly tall" characters were there because the matrix was 5x7, which didn't leave any room for descenders. Kind of a shame, as there were 12 pixel rows per character row in the video divider chain, plenty of room for both descenders and ascenders.

Comment: @jeffB: Many display fonts don't have descenders but shrink the g, p, q, and y characters to be five pixels tall like the rest of the lowercase letters; the Hitachi LCD font that's used all over the place uses a six-pixel-high "g" (which I find a bit irksome) but five-pixel-high p, q, and y.  Somewhat bizarrely, although most LCD displays have an eighth row of dots, but don't have ten rows, the common LCD controller font has alternate versions of g, j, p, q, and y which have three-row descenders, but not versions which have a single-row descender.

Comment: The TRS-80 official lowercase modification was that they'd solder on a piggyback chip and replace the character ROM with one that had better-looking lowercase letters.

Answer (score 4):

This answer has the Commodore 64, the Amstrad and the Sinclair ZX Spectrum and QL series in mind.

Note these home computers did not have a real "text" mode (as opposed to the more professional systems like IBM MDA, for example).

This means text needs to be displayed as graphics, and graphics needs resolution. A reasonably readable text font needs at least 5-6 pixels horizontal (business use would have required 8), and 8-10 pixels vertical size (including blank pixels to separate the characters from each other). Multiply that by 80 characters and you end up with resolutions >400 pixels horizontal, >200 vertical, which means at least 10k (better 16) of video memory, even with monochrome text, even more if you want more readable fonts, way more if you want at least four colors for your text. The Sinclair QL spent 32k of its scarce 128k for the video frame buffer, enabling it to display 85 characters by 25 lines in four colors.

With memory sizes from 16k to 48, maybe 64k on a typical home computer, 16k are not easily expendable.

That was the one reason - Another one is, once you got the pixels in the frame buffer, you need to get them out onto the screen - once every video frame, you need to clock out all the pixel data to the monitor. While this is done, the video circuitry needs exclusive access to the framebuffer and, in principle, halts the CPU (on simpler designs like most home computers, on more complex designs, the lockout of the CPU may be restricted to the framebuffer and it would still be able to work on other memory).

This means that the higher the screen resolution gets on such simple designs, the more the CPU needs to wait for access to the memory because it is locked out by the video circuitry (so-called "contended memory"). Some designs get across this using dual-ported memory, or dedicated memory chips for the frame buffer, but that is expensive.

Displays that work with a pure text mode storing characters in the frame buffer do not have this problems - Their video memory is much smaller (it doesn't need to store the pixels of a character, but rather only one byte for it's ASCII code), also their video output needs way less memory bandwidth. But again, home computers wanted graphics and a switchable graphics/text mode again uses circuity and thus costs money.

In the end, most 8 bit home computers restricted themselves to resolutions not much larger than 600 x 200 for these reasons.

Comment: 'Note most home computers did not have a real "text" mode' - the Spectrum and Amstrad didn't, but every other 8-bit computer I can think of did. What other exceptions am I missing?

Comment: 'pure text mode... needs way less memory bandwidth' - it needs less memory bandwidth from the frame buffer, but then also needs to fetch the character bitmaps; the total bandwidth needed is actually greater. Bad news: cannot use fast page mode to fetch the bitmaps. Good news: for truly pure text mode, most of the bandwidth only needs to come from a ROM which can be small.

Comment: 'A reasonably readable text font needs at least 5-6 pixels horizontal (business use would have required 8)' - that's an interesting suggestion - is there evidence that the business market wouldn't tolerate a 6-pixel font? I'm not saying you're wrong, just wondering where that claim comes from.

Comment: Hard to say what would be "tolerated". I remember the standard for printing used to be 7x9 for text with descenders. That would be an 8x10 cell on the screen. A lot of systems didn't bother with descenders and could therefore have 7x7 in an 8x8 cell. But less than 7 makes it tough. Absolute minimum that I remember is 5x7 which would be a 6x8 cell -> 80 x 24 would be 480x192. So that is doable - but ugly.

Comment: @rwallace The Acorn Electron, in some sense the BBC Micro, the Oric, the Sam Coupé, the Sharp MZ-800 and many, many more

Comment: @rwallace Ofc, does pure text mode need less bandwith. even without a line buffer it's 1/8th of what a bitmap for the same pixel resulution would need. with a line buffer (like in a 6845) it's 1/64th or less.

Comment: @rwallace You can pull the character data from an off-bus character ROM without consuming any bandwidth - That is what the IBM MDA did.

Comment: Tofro, as far as i understand the question it's about the real early machines, the generation of 76..78, way**before** C64, CPC or Spectrum.

Comment: @rwallace All "business" computers and terminals I know use a character grid at least 8 x 8. The other end of the scale is Tasword 2 for the ZX Spectrum using 4 a pixel wide font to display 64 characters...

Comment: @Raffzahn Where does he say that? Beyond that: (TV) Technology didn't change a lot for the next 20 years, the limits for the newer ones were the same as for the older ones.

Comment: Where does it say what?

Comment: @tofro BBC Micro has teletext mode, I think Oric does likewise. Good catch on the Electron. Teletext mode was a bad thing to cut out while simultaneously cutting the memory bandwidth. Overall, yes, you're right that for bitmapped display computers, memory and bandwidth were important limiting factors. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @rwallace I fear semantic weeds ahead. If you go with Raffzahn's interpretation that a pure text mode implies less bandwidth then those of the Oric and many others don't count because they're just an extra level of indirection. They **increase** bandwidth use — fetch once from RAM to get character code, compute address of that character row of data then fetch again *from RAM* to get the pixels. Twice as many fetches for a typical 1bpp 8-pixel character pattern. Even the C64, which has a bit of extra buffering, is still a net increase. Only if patterns are in ROM do you cut RAM bandwidth.

Comment: @Tommy Right, I'm not hung up about the terminology, but I think the distinction needs clarifying - which you have helped to do, thanks!

Comment: @Tommy Bandwith is *de*creased if the pixel fetch of the CRT controller can be made off-bus (maybe from a character ROM). Obviously, you're losing the possibility for user-defined characters, then.

Comment: @tofro understood and agreed; the Oric doesn't fit that pattern but e.g. the Apple II does, as does the BBC in teletext mode. So I think it affects what we're counting or not counting as a real text mode, especially if one of the issues at debate is which of those help with bandwidth limits, but it absolutely varies machine-to-machine.

Comment: On a 64K machine, fast page mode could have been used to fetch graphics if the LSB of each address was taken from the character code, and if the display controller alternated between fetching four bytes of character-select data and then four bytes of graphics data.

Comment: @Tommy: Reducing bandwidth also requires that characters which are fetched from RAM be held in some kind of buffer that can be replayed multiple times.  The Apple I video hardware did this (it actually used zero bytes of RAM to hold the display contents; the bulk data was held in six 1024x1 shift registers and the current line was held in a 40x6 shift register.

Comment: @supercat you're right, and have clearly thought this through more fully than I have; e.g. high resolution mode and text mode require exactly the same RAM bandwidth on an Apple II. Without an extra buffer such as the one you describe on the Apple I, you save storage but get identical bandwidth with a character ROM-based text mode versus the same resolution with directly-manipulable pixels.

Comment: @Tommy: One thing that would have been really nice on the C64 would have been an option to blank one scan line of each character row, and perform what would normally be badline cycles in the time slot given to character shape fetching.  That would have avoided the need to totally blank the display during CPU-intensive operations.

Answer (score 2):

> As I understand it, a black-and-white TV tube with no color burst signal and the RF stage skipped, while it could not quite reach 80 columns, could handle 64 columns well enough,

It can do 80 as well, but that's already borderline.

> which raises the question of why Apple and Commodore didn't try for that, or at least for something a bit beyond 40. 64x25 = 1600 bytes, not prohibitive even by the standards of the time.

As [Stephen Kitt](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/79/stephen-kitt) already [mentioned](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/columns-of-text-in-early-microcomputers#comment18511_6862), 1 KiB is a lot of memory, especially considering that the early machines like PET and Apple II were meant to work with as little as 4 KiB total RAM. The 'mere' 600 bytes needed for 64x25 would have been a rather deep cut.

Where Commodore and Apple stayed with a 'traditional 24/25 line display, Tandy did go a different way by making the screen 'binary' compatible with a 64x16 resolution - thus staying within the 1 KiB needed for display memory but showing longer lines.

> I get the impression memory bandwidth was a significant limitation, such that when the Apple II later added an 80-column option, the engineering of such involved the careful juxtaposition of two memory banks to provide data at the required rate.

Not in any way. Simple math tells that a 1 MHz machine with video a video access window on every clock can deliver 1 MB/s. A 40x24 screen at 60 Hz needs less than 60 kB/s, that's less 6%. There's much room for a larger display, even when including other constraints like frame structure.

The problem with the Apple II was that its timing is built around the video timing. The CPU doesn't get a monotone clock rate, but a varying one to make it fit. While this was a quite clever design, it's somewhat inflexible when data needs to be accessed at double the rate. Ofc, they could have went along and redesigned the whole timing - or doubled the machines speed (which would have been nice). The least intrusive way to double accessed data within the existing timing was adding just another KiB and make video access 16 bits wide.

> Was memory bandwidth the reason for Apple and Commodore sticking with 40 columns?

No. On the Apple side it's rather clear that WOZ intended the use of a TV set with (or without) intermediate RF. Thus 64 would be out of scope and 40 seams a nice thing.

For the PET, I can only guess that they tried to stay on the safe side (*1) - and, maybe more important wanted to keep 24 lines. With 24 lines 42 would have been possible - but that's really odd, isn't it?

We often forget here the other early machine, the Atari 400/800. Here, like with the Apple, a standard TV set was intended as main display, so 40x24 is a logical choice.

> If so, how did Tandy achieve 64 columns? Is it purely a coincidence that the 64-column machine is the only one of the trinity to use the Z80?

As soon as one is willing to diverge from the 24/25 lines paradigm, 64x16 is a quite reasonable choice. Especially when it comes with an 'internal' screen

> (I'm assuming the Vic-20 later supplying only 22 columns, is not so much due to technical limitations as to the use of a video chip designed more for games than general purpose computing.)

I think that's a good assumption.

Much like the TI 99/4 was designed around the use of a TV set. Here the standard mode was only 32x24 (a two color 40x24 was also available).

The C64 later on benefited from the 40x24 decision for the PET.

---

*1 - I would like to think that they did keep an eye on the use of a TV during design - and before the decision was made to produce an all-in-one unit.

Comment: Minor nit pick, not a big deal: unless you're assuming intermediate buffering, shouldn't the bandwidth calculation for a text screen be computed as bandwidth while painting pixels multiplied up? So e.g. the absolute least bandwidth necessary for a 40-column display would be 40 bytes in 52 microseconds, if you were risking using the entire "visible area" of the signal? Which I actually make about 770kb/sec. Then probably a bit more to allow a reasonable border.

Comment: Good points! Upvoted. But I'm not so sure about your reasoning on this point: 'A 40x24 screen at 60 Hz needs less than 60 kB/s, that's less 6%'. Overall per frame yes, but that way of measuring it assumes the video chip can cache a whole frame buffer, which it definitely could not. Even caching a line was by no means guaranteed to be available, not when cache costs over 50 transistors per byte and early microcomputers often didn't have an ASIC video chip. And if no cache and you look at the bandwidth requirements within the active part of a scan line...

Comment: according to http://pineight.com/mw/index.php?title=Dot_clock_rates the C64 has a pixel clock of 8.19 MHz at 320px = 40 col text, so if you assume 8x8 char matrix, 40 col text actually saturates the bandwidth on a 1 MHz machine. Maybe the bandwidth could have been increased in 1982, but seems less likely in 1977? Then the question is, how did Tandy break the apparent bandwidth limit?

Comment: The C64 not only saturates its bandwidth at 40 columns, but has to take the CPU off the bus for one line in eight during the visible period in order to cache the tile indices for that row. C64 types call them "bad lines".

Comment: @rwallace Tandy let the video chain clock through the static video RAM at its native pace. When the CPU needed access to video RAM, it took priority, and the video chain got zero values during the time it was pre-empted, showing up as black streaks. I'm trying to remember if there was a way to detect the vertical refresh interval and read/write only during that, but I think support for that technique was still in the future.

Comment: @rwallace No, it's realy only ~60 KiB with a line buffer - **not a frame buffer**.  As each character wil lget read once per frame. Without it's 60 x scan_lines_per_char KiB, as each character needs to be (re)read each scan line. With 8 scan lines per character it's ~480 KiB/s. still only half the bandwith available on an Apple or PET without hurting the CPU. Ofc, timing must be adjusted to fit the frame format, but that's not a big deal.Remember that these machines usually had a border area croping up some visible space? Thats the reason.

Comment: Now, the C64 is different when it comes to character generation then above early machines. All of them have an out-of-band character ROM. That means the character ROM was not part of the CPUs address space and it's access didn't take any bandwith (from CPU/Video). THe C64 is a different beast, as it's character data are stored in CPU address space. For every scan line of a character not only the character code had to be fetched from CPU address space, but also the resulting bitmap for this character and line. Since this would require way more than available ....

Comment: ... (at least without making the C64 considerable faster than 1 MHz), Commodore added a 40 character buffer. So instead of 16 memory access cycles per character 'only' 9 where needed, barely more than for a non buffering solution with out-of-band character ROM. Still it doubled the bandwith needed every 8th scan line, which was resolved by taking over some CPU cycles. So komplete different hardware to create the display, not realy comperable with the three early ones.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I think the Atari 400/800 also grab character-select data once per character row, so the number of stolen cycles on those machines is 360 per character line (unlike the Commodore 64, the CPU in that machine can be stalled on write cycles as well as reads, thus allowing individual cycles to be stolen).

Comment: @supercat Keep in mind that the Atari did run at 1.79 MHz, so no need to steal cycles. Also, the Atari is biuld arround a way different DMA structure. Not easy to compare. Last but not least, I did not argue about the way the Atari display ismanaged - just htat it alsofollows the 25 line aproach on a TV, thus having 40 characters per line.

Comment: @Raffzahn: The Atari's CPU and video share the same 1.79MHz bus, so *every* video or refresh cycle performed will mean one less cycle executed by the CPU, as distinct from the Apple II and VIC-20 where all video cycles are performed when the CPU wouldn't be using the bus anyway, or the Commodore 64 where most video cycles are performed when the CPU wouldn't be using the bus anyway.  On the Atari, all video cycles are performed at times when the CPU would otherwise be using the bus.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple II is the only one of the 1977 trinity to have memory mapped bitmap graphics: 280x192.  With a terribly small font 5x3, you could achieve 70 columns by 32 rows using the "hires" graphics mode.  Thank goodness there was a plethora of 80 column text cards that came out in the early 80's for the Apple II. The late Apple //e (1983) model had 80 columns builtin, but that was long after the trinity.

Comment: Flipping the hires pages can achieve 560x192, thus 80 column text: 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tV5bJIk8Lx8

Comment: The YouTube video doesn't show flicker, but I would expect there would have bene a fair bit, though I also supect that it could have been mitigated by applying the half-pixel shift to some scan lines on even frames and others on odd frames, and also by having the character-output routine and maybe even the CHRGET routine used by BASIC swap display pages.